# Python. Pygame - Interactive button does not respond

Tags: python, button, pygame

Just to clarify I am still a newbie to python and am trying to make two buttons that change colour due to interaction from the mouse. I am using a tutorial ([Tutorial Link](https://pythonprogramming.net/making-interactive-pygame-buttons/)) and it uses the mouses co-ordinates to trigger a new pygame rect to appear above the current one but in a different colour. I am getting a problem that when I hover my mouse over the button it does not change colour. I know that it is not from the current type of colours as I have tested with red and green. Any help and input is appreciated :)

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]

#Colours
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("BETA::00.0.1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():

  screen.fill(blue)

  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Broom!", largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))
  screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

  #Button

  if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))
  else:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

  if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))
  else:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

  pygame.display.flip()
  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(15)

  intro = True

  while intro:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         print(event)
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()


game_intro()
```

Comment: you have to check mouse position (and redraw rect) inside `while intro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do everything inside `while intro`

Beside you can use `pygame.Rect()` and `collidepoint(mouse)` to check mouse hover.

```
import pygame


# --- constants ---- UPPERCASE

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 480
SPEED = [2, 2]

# Colours

BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0,200,0)
RED = (200,0,0)
GREEN_BRIGHT = (0,255,0)
RED_BRIGHT = (255,0,0)

# --- functions ---

def text_objects(text, font):
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return text_surface, text_surface.get_rect()

def game_intro():

    large_text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    text_surf, text_rect = text_objects("Broom!", large_text)

    # center using screen
    text_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

    button_green_rect = pygame.Rect(75,400,100,50)
    button_red_rect = pygame.Rect(550,400,100,50)

    intro = True

    while intro:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # --- draws ----

        screen.fill(BLUE)

        screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

        #Button

        if button_green_rect.collidepoint(mouse):
              pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN_BRIGHT, button_green_rect)
        else:
              pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, button_green_rect)

        if button_red_rect.collidepoint(mouse):
              pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED_BRIGHT, button_red_rect)
        else:
              pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, button_red_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(15)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

pygame.display.set_caption("BETA::00.0.1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_intro()

pygame.quit()
```